# A variable/constant that inherits but does not share with the superclass, and does not share namespace

Tags: ruby, variables, constants

Is there a way to introduce some variable/constant with the the following three properties?

> a) It inherits a superclass's value when it is not assigned in the own class.
>
> b) It does not inherit other classes's value other than for superclasses's (even if they share the namespace).
>
> c) It does not overwrite the superclasses's value when assigned in the own class.

Using a class instance variable, a) is not satisfied.

```
class A; @foo = :foo end
class B < A; @foo end # => nil  (Does not satisfy (a))
class A; class C; @foo end end # => nil (Satisfies (b))

class B < A; @foo = :bar end
class A; @foo end # => :foo  (Satisfies (c))
```

Using a class variable, c) is not satisfied.

```
class A; @@foo = :foo end
class B < A; @@foo end # => :foo  (Satisfies (a))
class A; class C; @foo end end # => NameError (Satisfies (b))

class B < A; @@foo = :bar end
class A; @foo end # => :bar  (Does not satisfy (c))
```

Using a constant, b) is not satisfied.

```
class A; Foo = :foo end
class B < A; Foo end # => :foo  (Satisfies (a))
class A; class C; Foo end end # => :foo (Does not satisfy (b))

class B < A; Foo = :bar end
class A; Foo end # => :foo  (Satisfies (c))
```

I want something that behaves like this:

```
class A; something = :foo end
class B < A; something end # => :foo  (Satisfies (a))
class A; class C; something end end # => nil or Error (Satisfies (b))

class B < A; something = :bar end
class A; something end # => :foo  (Satisfies (c))
```

If it cannot be done simply by assigning and referencing a variable/constant, then is there any way to implement accessor methods that would have this property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create your own kind of accessor with the specific properties that you want. For example,

```
module InheritableProperty
  def property
    @property || superclass.property
  end
  def property=(value)
    @property = value
  end
end

class A
  extend InheritableProperty
end
class B < A
  extend InheritableProperty
  class C
    extend InheritableProperty
  end
end

A.property = 1
A.property # => 1
B.property # => 1
B::C.property # error

A.property = 1
B.property = 2
A.property # => 1
B.property # => 2
B::C.property # error

A.property = 1
B.property = 2
B::C.property = 3
A.property # => 1
B.property # => 2
B::C.property # => 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines suggested by joshuanapoli, I decided to go with this:

```
class A
  def self.foo; defined?(@foo) ? @foo : superclass.foo end
end

class A; @foo = :foo end
class B < A; foo end # => :foo
class A; class C; foo end end # => Error
class B < A; @foo = :bar end
class A; foo end # => :foo
```